Multiplying two real variables in D Wave
I have two real variables from dimod:
from dimod import Real

A = Real("A")

B = Real("B")

However, when I try to multiply them (A*B) I get the following error:
ValueError: REAL variables (e.g. 'A') cannot have interactions
Anyway to resolve this? I understand that binary and integer variables can be multipled without an issue, so what seems to be the problem with real variables?

Hi Dilshan, apologies for invading your SE question here. I'm super happy to see a fellow Sri Lankan in the quantum computing community. Please feel free to reach out if you'd like to connect. Dilhan.

Hi!
Sorry for the late response! I actually am new to this community and just saw from my inbox that I had received a message here! There is quite a lot of interest into the QC side of things from my company and they are hoping to build the QC community within the country. I will be happy to keep you informed of the progress and we can work together on this matter. The University of Colombo is also doing a lot of research on Quantum Computing, and Im quite excited about the future. Thanx for reaching out and I will be happy to connect with you

The dimod library from D-Wave is designed for modeling optimization problems for quantum and classical solvers, focusing on Ising models and quadratic unconstrained binary optimization (QUBO) problems. When you define variables using the Real, these are intended to represent real-valued variables within an optimization problem, not for general arithmetic operations.
For example, solving an optimization problem
\begin{align}
&\min x \cdot y\\
&\text{subject to}\\
&x + y = 1\\
&x, y \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
So, you can only represent a product (or a sum) of two variables within an optimization model, which the annealer will then optimize. To do this, see the examples page.

Thankyou so much.  I actually attempted to solve this through an optimization framework but it still yields the same error. For the purpose of making the question clear, I added the code for just the arithmetic operation. So if we take the example that you provided,
I would write the following code:
from dimod import ConstrainedQuadraticModel,  Real;
W1 = Real("W1");
W2 = Real("W2");
cqm.set_objective(W1*W2);
But when I run the last line of code (cqm.set_objective(W1*W2))
it returns to me the same error:
ValueError: REAL variables (e.g. 'W1') cannot have interactions

Also, thankyou for the link as well. I found one link there: https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/stable/examples/hybrid_cqm_diet.html#example-cqm-diet-reals , where it has multiplied two real variables (quantities[0] * quantities[1] ), but when I try it on my personal laptop it gives the same error : ValueError: REAL variables (e.g. 'rice') cannot have interactions. However, in the docs they seem to have got a solution, I also tried each of the different versions of dimod but all of them gave the same error. Thanks so much for all the assistance

@DilshanSonnadara, if you experience technical problems with D-Wave API, you can post your specific question and an error on D-Wave's support forum. I don't have D-Wave API on my computer, so I can't help with debugging. However, I suggest to run their examples as is and see if that works.

HI Monte, Thankyou so much for the suggestions. I will indeed do that and see how it progresses. Hoping for a good solution soon!
